# Pass data from one Fragment to another - SharedPreferences

Tags: android, android-fragments

On the `Fragment` class.. I had this line of codes

```
SharedPreferences pref = getActivity().getSharedPreferences("destination", MODE_PRIVATE);
Editor editor = pref.edit();
```

on this following codes, String dest already had a value.

```
public void onPlaceSelected(Place place) {
Log.i(LOG_TAG, "Place Selected: " + place.getName());
String dest = getString(R.string.place_data, place.getAddress());

edtDestination.setText(dest);

editor.putString("destination", dest);
```

But when fetched on the other activity. dest would return null...
`String destination = pref.getString("destination", "");`

Both classes extends Fragment

Comment: editor.commit() or  editor.apply()  after edit shared preference.

Comment: editor.commit() take time to apply data in preferences so just use editor.apply()

Comment: "Both activity extends Fragment" - I believe you mean both classes. Activities can't extend Fragment

Comment: @Bansal yeah! I forgot the `editor.commit();`.. thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

To commit changes in SharedPreferences

`editor.putString("destination", dest);
editor.apply();`

Answer (score 0):

Your question title says that you want to pass data from one fragment to another. If you want to do that, using SharedPreferences is not necessary. SharedPreferences should use for saving data, not for passing them.